# Is there a compression implementation with external metadata? Like Gzip or Brotli with external Huffman tree and LZW table

Tags: compression, gzip

I have a lot of messages in Kafka and want to use a compression. When message is compressed it consists of some metadata and compressed message itself.
My goal is to save space not for a single message but for all messages.
Maybe there is an implementation of Gzip that can take a bunch of messages, compress them, save the meta(Huffman tree and LZW table) and then use it for all messages?
This is what I have after compression, pseudocode describes data:

```
Huffman tree for message 1, LZW table for message 1, compressed message 1 in queue;
Huffman tree for message 2, LZW table for message 2, compressed message 2 in queue;
Huffman tree for message 3, LZW table for message 3, compressed message 3 in queue;
```

This is what I want to have after a compression, pseudocode describes data:

```
Common huffman tree and LZW table for all messages, stored separately.
compressed message 1 in queue;
compressed message 2 in queue;
compressed message 3 in queue;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're calling "metadata" is not metadata. It is the current description of Huffman codes or LZW codes to enable decompression. Metadata means associated information about the data that is not contained in the data, such as what is stored in a file system directory. E.g the name of the data, modification date, permission, author, source, etc. The compression coding information you are referring to is derived entirely from the data.

For LZW, that information is deeply intertwined with the compressed data and updated every symbol, and so cannot be saved and used on different data.

While you could in principle save the Huffman codes for an LZ77 compressor, that wouldn't do you much good. Most of the compression comes not from Huffman coding, but rather from matching strings. What you can do instead is save a "dictionary" of strings that occur commonly in your messages, and have that dictionary known on both the compression and decompression ends. Then you can use [zlib](https://zlib.net/) to [feed that dictionary](https://www.zlib.net/manual.html#Advanced) to the compressor and decompressor. The dictionary is 32K bytes, and can contain simply a concatention of however many example messages will fit. Or you can try to be more sophisticated and extract common strings, putting the most common at the end of the dictionary.

[zstd](https://github.com/facebook/zstd) also provides dictionary facilities.

Comment: Feels like the most of work will come from integrating these changes into Kafka. As far as I can see, this isn't natively supported by the queue, and as it's a distributed system things get complicated fast. It looks like the compression is done as a unit of work - independent and self-contained, and the compression state isn't shared. I couldn't find a settings option to plug in a dictionary for compression into Kafka. A reasonable option (though not an answer) might be to tweak available settings: algorithm (gzip/snappy/lz4/zstd), batch size, and linger timeout.